# camera and cheese not working

Tags: webcam, camera

all of a sudden cheese does not work. 
Webcam does not work (never tried it until now)

Gucview works

**running cheese in root mode works `gksu cheese`**

skype seems to work but not tested realtime

Possible cause.. 
I remember following instructions here for a bug to get a program to work or apt to install something it was refusing to install (not sure how to find it or what that program that did not work was).
But it said to delete something and then to reinstall skype and another thing.
This other thing was not installed so I did not reinstall or install it.
I am quite vague on this sorry.  But maybe the person here remembers and I can find the link and install that software.

Here is the output from entering cheese in term

```
~$ cheese
** Message: cheese-application.vala:211: Error during camera setup: No device found


(cheese:8126): cheese-CRITICAL **: cheese_camera_device_get_name: assertion 'CHEESE_IS_CAMERA_DEVICE (device)' failed

(cheese:8126): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'string != NULL' failed

(cheese:8126): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_schema_key_type_check: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:8126): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_type_string: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:8126): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_set_value: key 'camera' in 'org.gnome.Cheese' expects type 's', but a GVariant of type '(null)' was given

** (cheese:8126): CRITICAL **: cheese_preferences_dialog_setup_resolutions_for_device: assertion 'device != NULL' failed
```

Here is the output if I gksu cheese (**REMEMBER, THIS WORKS THOUGH**)

```
:~$ gksu cheese
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"
```

and here is the output from entering guvcview in term

```
~$ guvcview
GUVCVIEW: version 2.0.2
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
connect(2) call to /dev/shm/jack-1000/default/jack_0 failed (err=No such file or directory)
attempt to connect to server failed

(guvcview:8185): Gtk-WARNING **: gtk_widget_size_allocate(): attempt to allocate widget with width -43 and height 17

(guvcview:8185): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_distribute_natural_allocation: assertion 'extra_space >= 0' failed
```

Comment: It's definitely a permissions issue. Before systemd, you needed to be part of the video group to access the webcam. You might try adding yourself with `sudo usermod -a -G video $USER` (you'll need to logout and back in). However I am sceptical that this will work as this seems to be controlled with uaccess tags by udev (of which I know knowing). Also check that your webcam has the right permissions - can you post the output of `ls -l /dev/video0` (assuming you only have one webcame plugged in)?

Comment: I have already installed the gnome-system-tools to change/see users and groups.  I am a member of video   The output is as follows crw-rw-rw-+ 1 root video 81, 0 Jan 31 19:06 /dev/video0

Comment: What's the output of `getfacl /dev/video0`?

Comment: ~$ getfacl /dev/video0
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: dev/video0
# owner: root
# group: video
user::rw-
user:bksubhuti:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::rw-

Comment: I think I did a chmod 777 on this directory from a post I found.. it did nothing..

Comment: Oh I missed that you said Gucview works - as in as a non-root user? In which case I'm barking up the wrong tree and your `/dev/video0` permissions are fine (as indicated by the output of `getfacl` and `ls -l`. Not sure what to suggest. What's the terminal output of Cheese when run as a non-root user?

Comment: Could you put that in your original question rather than a comment, it will improve the readability?

Comment: Thanks for that - it'll help other people too. Unfortunately I'm not sure what the issue is. For those trying to help, it's getting stuck [in this method](https://git.gnome.org/browse/cheese/tree/libcheese/cheese-camera.c#n1555) in Cheese.

Comment: Check the output of gksu cheese.. added to main post

Comment: Just a hunch.. can you install qjackctrl on your machine and see if it breaks something.  I do not have it running.  but I saw a message in the guvcview that mentioned jack.

Comment: I'm not able to install Jack unfortunately. I'd like to say it's unrelated, although possibly it might be something to do with the built-in mic (I thought this appeared as a separate device however). Is there a particular reason you have Jack installed?

Comment: The problem is fixed probably with updates to the system

Comment: Glad to hear! Sorry I couldn't help further.

Answer (score 1):

Cheese and "camera" seems to work all of a sudden.  I would suspect it was from a linux kernel update or Elementary that I think happened.  If this happens to you, either run it as sudo or wait until another update comes.